# Misunderstanding getDerivedStateFromProps with Mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, observable, mobx, mobx-react

I have some misunderstanding how works `getDerivedStateFromProps` with Mobx observable objects. I know, that Mobx react to "reading" properties (through "dotting into"), trackable functions, etc.

For example, I have store with observable object.

```
class SomeStore {
    @observable
    status = {
        state: 'NOT_INITED',
    };

    @action
    async setStatusState = () => {
        this.status.state = 'STARTED';

        await something();
        this.status.state = 'ENDED';
    }

}
```

Next, I have injected component

```
@inject('someStore')
@observer
export default class SomeInjectedComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SomeComponent
                status={this.props.someStore.status}    
            />
        );
    }
}
```

End I have ended component

```
@observer
export default class SomeComponent extends Component {
    state = { isLoading: true }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        console.log(props.status.state);

        if (props.status.state === 'SUCCESS') {
            return { isLoading: false }
        }

        return null;
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isLoading) {
           return null;`enter code here`
        }

        return <div>Loading</div>
    }
}
```

Problem, that in `console.log(props.status.state)` I see only `NOT_INITED`, `STARTED`. But `ENDED` doesn't appear.

I guess because I haven't `this.props.status.state` in render method. If I add it in render (even only console.log) all works.

What should do I do to see changes in `getDerivedStateFromProps`?

Thank you.

Comment: if you look at the React LifeCycle, getDerivedStateFromProps is always before render, so that's the reason. BTW why not injecting directly to `SomeComponent ` ?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/425 and https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12310.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add "isLoading" flag to the your store. It would look something like this:

```
class SomeStore {
    @observable
    status = {
        isLoading: false,
        state: 'NOT_INITED',
    };

    @action
    async setStatusState = () => {
        this.status.state = 'STARTED';
        this.status.isLoading = true;

        await something();
        this.status.state = 'ENDED';
        this.status.isLoading = false;
    }

}
```

Your component

```
@observer
export default class SomeComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        const { isLoading } = this.props.status
        if (!isLoading) {
           return null;
        }

        return <div>Loading</div>
    }
}
```